# qrcode with amsart

Tags: qrcode

If I use qrcode with amsart I get extra vertical spacings in the resulting qrcode.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `amsart` class sets `\lineskiplimit` to 1pt, but `qrcode.sty` (wrongly) assumes it is 0pt.

Fix it by adding the expected setting in the appropriate places, when `qrcode` uses a `minipage` for printing the QR code.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\qr@printmatrix
  {\baselineskip}
  {\lineskiplimit=0pt\baselineskip}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\qr@printsavedbinarymatrix
  {\baselineskip}
  {\lineskiplimit=0pt\baselineskip}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists a competitive package `qrcode.tex` to the LaTeX package `qrcode.sty`. The `qrcode.tex` is designed for plain TeX but it can be used in LaTeX too because it is based only on TeX primitives.

You can compare

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
```

which gives wrong result with

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\input qrcode
\begin{document}
\qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
```

which gives correct result.